# Finding the total amount of cycles that would cover the set

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

Say I have an set of integers $\{1,2,3,4\}$. The cycles that I mentioned in the title are specimens of cycling notation from group theory. I want to find a formula, that would give me all possible arrangements of cycles that’d cover the set and be at least two in length. For example, with above mentioned set these configurations are possible:
$$(1234)$$
$$(1243)$$
$$(1324)$$
$$(1342)$$
$$(1423)$$
$$(1432)$$
$$(12)(34)$$
$$(13)(24)$$
$$(14)(23)$$
Therefore, the expected output would be $6\cdot1+3\cdot2=12$ cycles.

Perhaps this problem can be simplified into simpler term, which is also welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking for "Number of cycles in all derangement permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$," tabulated at https://oeis.org/A162973

No closed form formula is given there (which is some evidence that no closed form formula is known), but there is the asymptotic formula, $a(n) \sim e^{-1}n!  (\log(n) + \gamma - 1)$, where $\gamma$ is Euler's gamma constant. You'll also find programs for computing it, and an exponential generating function.

Comment: Since my task only involves sets of max size of 12, this sequence perfectly fits my use case. I also thank you for providing a formal definition of what I was looking for